# angular.elemnt(btn-id).html(). I am getting undefined

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

- I have a js file on sample/scripts/sample.js and there are 8 html
  files on sample/src/templates/ .html .
- I wanted to select a button on one of the html file.
- I tried angular.elemnt(btn-id).html(). I am getting undefined. I am
  doing wrong?

angular.elemnt(btn-id).html()

- I wanted to change the text of button according the condition

Comment: I'd try spelling element correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have element spelled wrong, but angular.element is not used to return element references. You want to use document.getElementById().

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: so I should use document.getElementById()instead of  angular.elemnt(btn-id).html()  ???

Comment: Yes. That's all it takes.